# „Ich frag mich wer wir sind“ aus dem Lied „Wir sind Wir“ des deutschen DJs Paul van Dyk

Tags: pronoun, lyrics, interrogative

Ich höre das Lied *[Wir sind Wir](https://web.archive.org/web/20160307151947/https://www.tape.tv/paul-van-dyk/videos/wir-sind-wir)* des deutschen DJs Paul van Dyk, und kapiere nicht, warum im Satz *[ich frag mich wer wir sind](https://www.songtexte.com/songtext/paul-van-dyk-and-peter-heppner/wir-sind-wir-7bcfea9c.html)* das Interrogativpronomen *wer* anstelle des Personalpronomens *wir* steht. Ist dieser Satz nicht ein Gleichsetzungssatz (mit *sein*) wie er bei [Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-wer-was.html) geschrieben ist?

[image]

Comment: Seriously, I was slowly scrolling down, looking for something to counter your example … and then I stumbled upon Canoo.net’s horrific typo. No, that sentence on Canoo.net should read ***wer** sind wir.* Don’t ask me how that happened; probably autocorrect with the grammar option turned on.

Comment: Äh … und frag mich auch nicht, warum der Kommentar da auf Englisch steht o.o''

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dort hat Canoo.net einen schweren Bock geschossen. Wahrscheinlich haben sie eine Autokorrektur mit Grammatikfunktion benutzt. Diese ist dann an der deutschen Wortstellung gescheitert, und hat aus *wer* ein *wir* gemacht. Anders kann ich es mir nicht erklären, denn auf der Tastatur sind *e* und *i* ausreichend weit voneinander entfernt, dass man nicht versehentlich das falsche trifft.

Tatsache ist: die einzig richtige Form ist:

> **Wer** sind wir?

Und im Liedtext muss ein Komma rein:

> Ich frage mich**,** wer wir sind.

Comment: .. Ich wusste es nicht, dass es Fehler bei Canoo.net gibt :)  Meine Lehrerin sagte mir immer "Canoo ist die beste Seite".. trotz alledem danke ich dir immer ;)

Comment: Naja, hinter Canoo.net stehen auch nur Menschen … ;) (@mle)

Comment: Ich halte es für wahrscheinlicher, daß es ein menschengemachter Fehler ist. Es passiert leicht, daß man beim Schreiben gedanklich schon ein paar Wörter weiter ist, und gerade sehr ähnliche Wörter können dann einmal durcheinandergeraten. Das gibt es schon bei handschriftlichen Abschriften aus der Zeit lange vor Erfindung des Computers. – Ich habe Canoo jedenfalls auf den Fehler hingewiesen und gehe davon aus, daß er demnächst behoben wird.

Answer (score 4):

Man muss zwischen der Behauptung bzw. Aussage

> 1. **Wir** sind wir.

und der Frage

> 2. **Wer** sind wir?

unterscheiden.

Der erste Satz ist eine Gleichsetzung, also eine spezielle Form einer Aussage. Das fett hervorgehobene »*Wir*« am Beginn des Satzes ist das Subjekt, und das »*wir*« am Ende des Satzes ist ein Nominativobjekt, das nur bei Gleichsetzungen auftreten kann. Das heißt, dass das Prädikat eine Form des Verbs »sein« sein muss. Eine alternative Bezeichnung dafür ist »Gleichsetzungsnominativ«.
(Der Vollständigkeit halber: Die grammatischen Rollen der beiden *wir*s kann man auch umgekehrt interpretieren. Vergleiche dazu: »Wir sind Menschen« - »Menschen sind wir«)

Der zweite Satz ist eine Frage, die von dem Fragewort (Interrogativpronomen) »*Wer*« eingeleitet wird. Grammatisch nimmt es die Rolle des Subjekts ein. Die beiden anderen Worte (*sind wir*) haben dieselbe Rolle wie im ersten Satz. Auch hier liegt eine Gleichsetzung im grammatischen Sinn vor.

Comment: Den ersten Satz gibt es aber nur in Bayern, und da wird er meist lokal eingefärbt zu 'Mir san mir!' :) .

Comment: @userunknown: Der erste Satz ist ein völlig korrekter hochdeutscher Satz, daher *gibt* es ihn überall wo Deutsch gesprochen wird. (Ob er überall häufig ausgesprochen wird, ist etwas anderes, wurde von dir aber nicht postuliert.) Der Satz »Mir san mir« ist hingegen ein Satz in einem Dialekt, also so etwas wie einer anderen Sprache. Den *gibt* es dort, wo dieser Dialekt gesprochen wird. Da aber ein Dreiwortsatz allein noch keinen Dialekt definiert, ist es kein Wunder, dass man den Satz »Mir san mir« auch außerhalb Bayerns antrifft, unter anderem auch in meiner Heimat Österreich.